# Diferencia al instanciar ArrayList<>

Tags: java, lista, arraylist

Veo en mi proyecto que se utiliza indistintamente la manera de instanciar nuevas listas (he visto dos maneras distintas), pero que a priori, funcionan igual, y no me queda claro por qué usar una u otra.
Por ejemplo:

```
List<Entidad> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

o

```
List<Entidad> list2 = new ArrayList<Entidad>();
```

- ¿Qué diferencia hay entre list y list2?
- Entiendo que list2 sólamente puede ser rellenado con objetos Entidad, mientras que list, ¿puede ser rellenado con objetos Entidad y clases Padre/Hija?
- ¿Hay alguna otra diferencia?

Comment: Si no estoy equivocado, es solo azúcar sintáctico. Ambas formas son equivalentes y la única diferencia está en la escritura.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se puede decir que no hay diferencia, únicamente que en este caso:

```
List<Entidad> list = new ArrayList<Entidad>();
```

en tiempo de ejecución `ArrayList<Entidad>()` es solo una `ArrayList`, el único beneficio es que cuando escribes el código definiendo el tipo en el `ArrayList` el compilador va a verificar que no definas un tipo inapropiado, por lo tanto, el argumento de tipo explícito `Entidad`, se puede reemplazar simplemente con el operador de diamante `<>`, ya que es redundante definir el tipo. Define simplemente:

```
List<Entidad> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: Para completar lo perfectamente explicado, creo que aun se vera la declaracion explicita porque era lo utilizado en las versiones de Java de la 6 hacia atras y algunos developers aun la utilizan por costumbre

Answer (score 3):

No hay ninguna diferencia, pero si pasas analizadores de código aparece un warning ya que se entiende como código redundante el caso de list2.

Esta seria la forma mas optima de declarar:

```
List<Entidad> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

Answer (score 2):

Sumando a lo anteriormente comentado, dado

```
List<Entidad> list = new ArrayList<Entidad>();
```

desde Java 7 puede escribirse usando el operador diamante para que *infiera el tipo* de la derecha de la siguiente forma:

```
List<Entidad> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

desde Java 10 es posible usar *inferencia de tipos* con `var` de la siguiente forma:

```
var list = new ArrayList<Entidad>();
```